# Cocoa application hides on deactivate

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument, nsapplication

If i switch my NSDocument based app to another app, or switch the space, my app hides...

**Cannot figure out what causes this behavior...**

Note that `Hides on deactivate` is set to NO in the main window

Comment: Have you tried "windowName setCanHide:NO"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was, that i was adding a child window with

```
addChildWindow
```

And this window had checked '`Hide on deactivates`'